# Проблемы с сохранением данных

Tags: ios, swift

Пытаюсь сохранить значения, все работает, но когда сбрасываю ключи в в функции `application` `AppDelegate.swift` таким образом:

```
    let domain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
    UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: domain)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

получаю что переменная selectedHourlyMoneyCurrency равна 0.0, а должна по идее 1.0

код:

```
var selectedHourlyMoneyCurrency: Float {
        get {
            if let hourlyMoneyCurrency = UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "HourlyMoneyCurrency") as Float?  {
                print(hourlyMoneyCurrency); return hourlyMoneyCurrency
            } else  { return 1.0 }
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "HourlyMoneyCurrency")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
    }

  func initMoneySettings() {
        moneyCurrency.text! = moneyCurrency.text! + String(selectedHourlyMoneyCurrency) + " " + selectedMoneyCurrency
    }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initMoneySettings()
    }
```

Comment: Что то я не понял идею. Эта команда очищает все значения UserDefaults. Она и очищает. Что не так то?

Comment: после чистки, при считывании переменной selectedHourlyMoneyCurrency возвращается ноль, а должен 1.0

Comment: Для чего вы используете эту чистку? И нет, не должен, вы же очистили ее значение.

Comment: Чистку использую для проверки как это будет работать на устройстве, в get переменной идет же проверка, если нету ключа, тогда возвращаем дефолтное значение 1.0, я не пойму почему 0) С такой записью все работает как необходимо - UserDefaults.standard.object(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что UserDefaults.standard.float возвращает 0, если нет ключа, а не nil. Сделайте проверку на 0 в коде.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey:)` для удаления значений. Тогда гарантированно вернется `nil`.

Comment: UserDefaults.standard.float все равно вернет 0, попробуйте :)